# Create react app, remove relative path - global folders in Typescript

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, directory-structure

I have a folder src/Types

```
import {  people  } from "../Types";
```

In more nested components I do

```
import {  people } from "../../Types";
```

What I would like to do is just

```
import { people } from "Types";
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports)?